# Custom DependencyProperty not bindable with viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, dependency-properties

Consider this attached property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TestImage",
    typeof(BitmapSource), typeof(TestView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public static void SetTestImage(UIElement element, BitmapSource value)
{
    element.SetValue(TestImageProperty, value);
}

public static BitmapSource GetTestImage(UIElement element)
{
    return (BitmapSource)element.GetValue(TestImageProperty);
}

public BitmapSource TestImage
{
    get
    {
        return GetTestImage(this);
    }
    set
    {
        SetTestImage(this, value);
    }
}
```

And the `XAML`:

```
<common:UserControlBase x:Class="MyViews.TestView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyViews"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:MyCommon.Common;assembly=MyCommon.Common"
    xmlns:mefed="clr-namespace:MEFedMVVM.ViewModelLocator;assembly=MEFedMVVM.WPF"
    mefed:ViewModelLocator.SharedViewModel="MyViewModel"
    views:TestView.TestImage="{Binding TestImage}"
```

Hence, I'm binding the view's `TestImage` property to the viewmodel's `TestImage` property! Then, from code-behind I update the property:

```
this.TestImage = image;
```

**This does NOT trigger the setter in my viewmodel.**

What is causing this?

Comment: Have you set the _DataContext_?

Comment: It *will* be set by the `ViewModelLocator` (when the control is loaded, I think). Is that too late?

Comment: No, there is no "too late" to change the _DataContext_. When the DataContext is changed, all the Binding using this DataContext are updated.

Comment: have you tried UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged or TwoWay Mode in your binding ?

Comment: When you write `views:TestView.TestImage="{Binding TestImage}"` you bind the property to itself. What's the sense in that? Or is there another `TestImage` property in some VM class?

Comment: @Clemens, not necessarily? The viewmodel (DataContext) also has a TestImage property.

Comment: @HichemC, nandayo! `TwoWay` did the trick. Why not answer the question? :)

Comment: Ah ok, I just edited my comment. You should add that to your question, otherwise it's really cryptic. But why is it an attached property after all? And you could set [FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx).

Comment: I was actually going to ask about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `Binding` on `TwoWay` Mode will resolve the problem.